# Right align contents of a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

This is my first question in stack overflow. Please be liberal in validating it against the posting etiquette. which I am trying to adhere to.

I am attempting to create an android application for Honeycomb tablets, in which an activity loads a layout with fragments.  Please see [this](http://cads-sharepoint.co.uk:8090/sites/ftp/user1/Image1.png) image for better communication.

As seen that image, I have an activity running on emulated tablet. That activity has a listfragment on its left and and a fragment layout on right. The listfragment displays texts in a list. My need is that I have to have these texts in the listfragment to be aligned to right side of the fragment.

I had searched this site and many others but can find solutions about aligning an image on right of these text items in this list and not the text itself. I had attempted to use gravity property on the fragment and that too did not help.

Is this possible at all? Any suggestions on this will help me a lot.

Thanks,
Narayanan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the layout that defines the list, the item's gravity property simply works fine.